# Why is this material so bright even without any lights?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I am following a tutorial from Blender Guru making a donut. When rendering with Cycles my sprinkles glow, even hiding the light does not help. Cant find a way to fix this.

[image]

Comment: Can you upload the .blend file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your roughness value on the principled bsdf is way to high, it should be between 0-1. Having a really high value like that can make the shader behave abnormally.

Comment: That did the trick. I was so sure I checked all the values. Thank you!